# ctypes を使った ptrace の呼び出し結果が予想と異なる

Tags: python, linux

https://shishirsubedi.com.np/htb/doctor/

上記サイトのModifying the exploit to get the final valuePermalinkの項目がよくわかりません。

そのためか、Updated exploit.pyの項目をそのまま実行すると、nameerrorが出てきました。
valとは何ですか？何が原因か、教えてください。

自分はコードは基本的に読めず、要所を検索しながら読んでいます。

追記：
valをfinalに変えたところ、以下の結果となりました。pidを間違えたのでしょうか、条件がいまいちわかりません。
`ps -ef | grep -i apache`で出たpidは３桁でした。

```
Instruction Pointer: 0x0
Injecting Shellcode at: 0x0
Shellcode Injected!!
Final Instruction Pointer: 0x2
```

Comment: ざっと見では変数 `final` を使うのが正しそうですね。確認はしていません。

Comment: ＠mjy　回答ありがとうございます。nameerrorは直りましたが、まだコードがおかしいようです。追記しました。

Comment: `PTRACE_ATTACH` した後に `waitpid` などをしないと、次の `ptrace` の呼び出しで成功する確率が低くなります。
なお、リンク先の記事に依存せずに、回答者に問題が理解・再現できるようにして下さい。
[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)が参考になります。